# Angular 4 - Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: angular, build, angular2-aot

One of my feature modules has this content:

```
declare function require(name: string);

@NgModule({
imports: [
// other modules here
ChartModule.forRoot(
  require('highcharts'),
  require('highcharts/highcharts-more'),
  require('highcharts/modules/funnel'),
  require('highcharts/modules/heatmap')
)
```

It runs fine locally but when I build it with the prod flag it fails. The error I get is:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a non-exported function (position 26
>   :18 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol ....
>
> ERROR in ./src/main.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in ...

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but with `export const`

Comment: Faced a similar issue on a `.forRoot(aVariable)` call under `@NgModule` where `aVariable` was being calculated by a series of function calls - had to `export` *all functions* involved in that call chain (`function` -> `export function`) to get the issue to go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't point you to the exact line, because you didn't include the full `@NgModule` decorator. This fault is normally in the `providers` array, when you have something like this:

```
@NgModule({
// imports, exports and declarations
  providers: [{
    provide: XSRFStrategy, 
    useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('RESPONSE_TOKEN', 'RESPONSE_TOKEN') 
  }]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

You cannot use AOT when you have an inline function call like that. So instead, replace `useValue` with `useFactory` and an exported function (as stated in your error message).

Here is the AOT-safe version of my first listing:

```
export function xsrfFactory() {
  return new CookieXSRFStrategy('XSRF-TOKEN', 'X-XSRF-TOKEN');
}
@NgModule({
// imports, exports and declarations
  providers: [{
    provide: XSRFStrategy,
    useFactory: xsrfFactory
  }]
})
export class MyModule {}
```